# Web View Not Loading HTML content

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading check string inside a webview

```
String Check = "<html><body><form action=\"https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/**ID**\" id=\"BB_BuyButtonForm\" method=\"" +
            "post\" name=\"" +"BB_BuyButtonForm\" target=\"_top\">"
            +"<input name=\"item_name_1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"Carbon Emission\"/>"
            +"<input name=\"item_description_1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"Pay for carbon emission. \"/>"
            +"<input name=\"item_quantity_1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\"/>"
            +"<input name=\"item_price_1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"ffff\"/>"
            +"<input name=\"item_currency_1\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"USD\"/>"
            +"<input name=\"_charset_\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"utf-8\"/>"
            +"<input alt=\"\" src=\"https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/buy.gif?merchant_id=**ID**&amp&w=117&amp&h=48&amp&style=trans&amp&variant=text&amp&loc=en_US\" type=\"Button\"/>"
            +"</form></body></html>";
```

Then i loading check string to webview

```
        webview.loadData(Check, "text/html", "UTF_8");
```

Its showing white screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much to Nappy and Sandy.

Finally i solved my problem.It was because of secure url https .This will not run in webview directly so we have to avoid the ssl error

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSSLError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);                 
      view.proceed();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Class like following

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Then add this statement

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

after

```
webview.loadUrl(authUrl);
```

Comment: yes i have added already,as i am creating linked integration so i have added it priviously

Comment: @AndroidDev let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2216/discussion-between-sandy-and-androiddev)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to change

> setInitialScale(1);

to

> setInitialScale(100);

because the parameter expects a per cent value.