# show webpage from webview

Tags: android

i am able to open google.com from emulator browser.but in coding i am not able to show any thing.that is my code.i already write internet permission.any extra emulator setting?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity 
{
    WebView webview;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","192.168.0.2");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","8080");

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979797/webview-not-showing-url-content/6980075#6980075

Comment: thanks for reply but i already did all stuff.it's not working.it show me"the web page at 'http://google.com' temporarily down or it may be move permanently".Any other emulator setting?

Comment: Please make sure that internet permission statement is correct ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" > </uses-permission>`

Comment: no sandy i have checked many times.one more question i want to ask,Is android emulator browser support pdf file?can i open pdf file by url in android emulator?

Comment: Browser does not support pdf. To view pdf through browser you have to install pdf viewer. <uses-permission> tag should have only one parent that is <manifest>. If u put permission statement in correct position then you will see Internet permission on permission tab. Pls check that also..

Comment: yes internet permission showing correctly.i install pdf viewer.i have to fetch pdf from url.can you give me some tips?

Answer (score 3):

open CMD prompt and go to SDK path...

```
D:\Android Setup\android-sdk-windows\tools
```

write down this following command...

```
emulator -avd "name" -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it's not working.it show me"the web page at 'google.com'; temporarily down or it may be move permanently".Any other emulator setting?